# Dual boot problems

Tags: linux, boot, windows, dual-boot

I have 2 SSD's. One SSD has windows installed. Then I attempted to install arch-linux on the second SSD. Everything seemed to be working when I boot into linux, but when I boot into windows it does a "disk check". When I attempt to boot back into the other hard drive, there is no boot option for my Linux hard drive. I am assuming that I have setup my partitions and grub incorrectly.

So the windows hard drive has an EFI partition and I have never touched it. My Linux hard drive also has an EFI partition with grub installed to it. This is my first time attempting to install 2 operating systems on 2 hard-drives. So I was wondering if windows just doesn't like that I have 2 EFI partitions and it sabotages my Linux harddrive? Should I install grub into the windows EFI partition? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, do you se UEFI native mode? Do you have ``.efi`` files both for Windows and GRUB of EFI partition?

Comment: @user996142 windows EFI has "/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi" and linux EFI has  "/EFI/boot/grubx64.efi" . My ASUS bios says "Boot Device Control = UEFI and Legacy OPROM" and "Boot from Storage Devices = Legacy only"

Answer (score 0):

you have to install grub on the partition/disk of windows .Of course, you should (if you have not already done so) to install ntfs3g and osprobe in Archlinux ,so you can see the partitions /disks ntfs .
You can use a live debian-*buntu to do all this.
example:

```
su
blkid
```

(to get all the information on the disks and partitions)

*Mount the partition on which the system resides

`sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt` (change with your /root partition archlinux)

*Mount the rest of the devices with the command:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

*Do a chroot on your system.

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

install Grub2 in the MBR:

```
grub-install /dev/sda (if it is the right partition)
update-grub2
```

**If you get errors you can try again :

```
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
```

*Exit from the chroot:

```
exit
```

*Remove all devices:

```
cd ~
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/

reboot
```